# Office Dialog API with single-page application throwing error

Tags: javascript, ms-word, dialog, office-js, office-addins

I am working on an add-in and it's an Angular single page application. Currently it has only one controller ( one screen ). Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#use-the-office-dialog-api-with-single-page-applications-and-client-side-routing):

> If your add-in uses client-side routing, as single-page applications
>   typically do, you have the option to pass the URL of a route to the
>   displayDialogAsync method, instead of the URL of a complete and
>   separate HTML page.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="ms-Button ms-Button--compound" id="addPlaceholder" ng-click="openPopup()">
    <span class="ms-Button-label">Open Popup</span><span class="ms-Button-description">Open Popup</span>
</button>
```

**Controller code**

```
researchApppBuilderModule.controller('researchcontroller', ['$scope', '$location',
            function ($scope, $location) {

                var urlRoot = $("base").first().attr("href");
                $scope.openPopup = function () {
                    var dialog;
                    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(urlRoot + '/app/research', { height: 30, width: 20 },
                        function (asyncResult) {
                            dialog = asyncResult.value;

                        });
                }
    }]);
```

I have tested this route within the Add-in and it's working. So, I know the route is correct.

So, this code opens up a dialog but with an error:

ADD-IN ERROR:

Sorry, we cannot load the add-in. Please make sure you have network and/or Internet Connectivity. Click "Retry" once you're back online.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtprp.jpg)

I tried searching in the documentation but couldn't find anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Although you "can" pass a route to the `displayDialogAsync` method, I don't recommend it for reasons given in the note just below the paragraph of documentation that you quoted: An entirely new instance of your add-in is launched in the dialog. This means that the app goes through its initialization code. This usually confuses the routing strategy and the dialog ends up trying to navigate to a URL that is an invalid combination of the default route and the route that you passed to the method, like `https://example.com/app/#/app/research`.

I recommend that create a research.html page and pass the URL of it to the dialog (as this sample does: [Word-Add-in-AngularJS-Client-OAuth](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-AngularJS-Client-OAuth/blob/cc1c4440cbb8caa85dc737c726420d420722e57c/app/home/login.controller.js)). This may seem to deviate from the purity of a single page app; but you're doing that anyway when you pass a route to the method, because you are really passing a second instance of the app's "single page" (because you're launching a second instance of the whole app).

Otherwise, you can troubleshoot, by having the callback to `displayDialogAsync` log the `asyncResult.error.code` and `asyncResult.error.message` properties to the console. I also recommend that you read [Use the Dialog API | Handle errors and events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#handle-errors-and-events). You could also use the Fiddler tool or the Charles tool to see what URL the dialog is trying to open.

Finally, your code doesn't show what the `urlRoot` is. Be sure it is an absolute URL including the HTTPS protocol.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that we "always" have to run our app over HTTPS ?. Currently, we let our clients decide whether they want to run our app over HTTP or HTTPS. Currently I am running my app locally over HTTP.

Comment: The best part is, "displayDialogAsync" is not throwing any error. Value of asyncResult.status is "succeeded".